# Separating and executing command line arguments using execvp()

Tags: c, fork, command-line-arguments, execvp

The code below works fine for what it does. I enter any 2 commands, in this case ls and pwd, and the terminal outputs the result of those commands, plus the PID for the child that ran it.

Command line looks like this currently:
./practice.c ls pwd

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

   long cpid1, cpid2;

   switch(cpid1 = fork()){
      case -1:
         perror("fork failed");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;

      case 0:
         printf("First child, pid=%d, executing command...\n", getpid());
         execvp(argv[1], NULL);
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   wait(NULL);
   switch(cpid2 = fork()){
      case -1:
         perror("fork failed");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      
      case 0:
         printf("Second child, pid=%d, executing command...\n", getpid());
         execvp(argv[2], NULL);
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   while(wait(NULL) != -1);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

However, I want the user to enter a command line that looks more like this:
./practice.c pwd , ls -l

So, first of all my problem is separating out the command line. "PWD" would be argv[1], then "," would be argv[2], then "ls" would be argv[3] and so on.  What I really want is to use the commas as delimiters. Even then, in the case of "ls -l" I want that to be 1 arg so when I run exec it will look like all I did was run execvp("ls", "-l", NULL). Any tips or tricks you recommend?

Comment: Note that you'd have something like `char *args[3] = { "ls", "-l", NULL };` (with the values deduced from `argv` — and you'd need to size `args[]` based on the number of arguments before or after the argument containing `,` only), and then invoke `execvp(args[0], args);`.  The notation you show for the call to `execvp()` would be applicable to `execlp()`, but only when you know the number of arguments at compile time.

Comment: To run `ls -l`  with `execlp` you have to call `execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);` The first `"ls"` is the command to call. The second `"ls"` is passed as `argv[0]` when running the excutable.

Comment: Your existing code gives the invoked program no arguments.  That's not recommended.  Again, you should create an array and use that: `char args[2] = { argv[1], NULL }; … execvp(args[0], args);`.  Similarly of course for `argv[2]` and the second command.  With the revised requirements, you'll need to accumulate arguments up to the `,` argument, then run it.  You could find the index of the comma argument and replace that with `NULL` and work from there.

Comment: On an unrelated note, remember that the "arguments" you pass to `execvp` (currently `NULL`) is what becomes the `argv` array inside the executed program. By passing `NULL` you say that there isn't an `argv` array at all, and there isn't even `argv[0]` inside the new program. If you don't want to pass any arguments to the new program I suggest you use `axeclp` instead, as in `execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring some comments into an answer.*</sup>

Note that you'd have something like:

```
char *args[3] = { "ls", "-l", NULL };
```

(with the values deduced from `argv` — and you'd need to size `args[]` based on the number of arguments before or after the argument containing comma (`,`) only), and then invoke `execvp(args[0], args);`. The notation you show for the call to `execvp()` would be applicable to `execlp()`, but only when you know the number of arguments at compile time.  In your revised requirement, you don't know the number of arguments at compile time, which is why you need to use `execvp()`.

Your existing code gives the invoked program no arguments. That's not recommended. Again, you should create an array and use that:

```
char args[2] = { argv[1], NULL };
…
execvp(args[0], args);
```

Similarly of course for `argv[2]` and the second command. With the revised requirements, you'll need to accumulate arguments up to the comma argument, then run it. You could find the index of the comma argument and replace that with NULL and work from there.

This code extracts the execution into a function, `execute()`, leaving the `main()` function to split the argument list, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void execute(char **args);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int arg1 = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ",") == 0)
        {
            argv[i] = NULL;
            execute(&argv[arg1]);
            arg1 = i + 1;
        }
    }
    if (argv[arg1] != NULL)
        execute(&argv[arg1]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void execute(char **args)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        char **argv = args;
        while (*argv)
            printf("[%s]", *argv++);
        putchar('\n');
        printf("Child pid=%d executing command %s...\n", getpid(), args[0]);
        execvp(args[0], args);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: failed to execute command %s\n", getpid(), args[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1)
            printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }
}
```

The program source is in `vp13.c`; the program is `vp13`.  When run like this, it produces:

```
$ vp13 ls -l , pwd , ls -C -F , date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
[ls][-l]
Child pid=54602 executing command ls...
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jonathanleffler  staff  9076 Dec  3 21:18 vp13
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathanleffler  staff  1148 Dec  3 21:18 vp13.c
drwxr-xr-x  3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Dec  3 21:15 vp13.dSYM
Child 54602 exited with status 0x0000
[pwd]
Child pid=54603 executing command pwd...
/Users/jonathanleffler/soq/so-6513-7710
Child 54603 exited with status 0x0000
[ls][-C][-F]
Child pid=54604 executing command ls...
vp13*      vp13.c     vp13.dSYM/
Child 54604 exited with status 0x0000
[date][+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S]
Child pid=54605 executing command date...
2020-12-03T21:23:55
Child 54605 exited with status 0x0000
$
```

I trust that isn't too flexible for you.

Comment: I am just a little lost on the array of argv part. It almost seems like we don't have enough information considering the user can have any number of arguments on the command line, with any number of flags for each argument. Where it says                                    
        char **argv = args;
        while (*argv)
            printf("[%s]", *argv++); Could I get a little more explanation here? Just so I fully get exactly what's happening

Comment: You might observe that I showed the test run with 3 commas (so 4 commands), and that 2 of the commands had 1 argument and 1 command had 3 arguments. The `argv` printing loop works by observing that the argument vector (*arg*ument *v*ector) contains pointers to a series of strings terminated by a null pointer. The loop checks that `*argv` is not null (`while (*argv)` is equivalent to `while (*argv != NULL)`), and then prints the argument surrounded by square brackets `[]` which helps you spot some forms of confusion (newlines in the string; carriage returns in the string, etc). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The post-increment changes `argv` so it points to the next string.  Some variant on that loop is a basic tool for debugging command construction.  You can see the output from that loop in the sample output.  The loop around `wait()` is another basic tool for debugging command execution.

Comment: I see. Thank you I really understand a lot more now!